# How can I deal with "This event loop is already running" error on a nested function in asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to execute web scraping with a set of categories, and each category also has a list of URLs. So I decided to call a function based only on each category in the main function, and within the inner function there is a non-blocking call.

So here is the code:

```
def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    b = loop.create_task(f("p", all_p_list))
    f = loop.create_task(f("f", all_f_list))

    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(p, f))
```

It should execute the `f` function concurrently.

But the `f` function also has to run the loop, since in the function it calls a function simultaneously, based on each URL.

```
async def f(category, total): 
    urls = [urls_template[category].format(t) for t in t_list]
    soups_coro = map(parseURL_async, urls)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = await loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*soups_coro))
```

But after I run the script, it got an `This event loop is already running` error, and I found that it is because I call `loop.run_until_complete()` in both inner and outer functions.

However, when I strip the `run_until_complete()`, and just call `f()` in the `main()`, the function call immediately got finished and it cannot wait for the inner function to finish. So it is inevitable to call the loop in the `main()`. But then I think it is incompatible with the inner function, which also must call it.

How can I deal with the problem and run the loop? The orinigal code is all in the same `main()` and it worked, but I want to make it cleaner if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I deal with the problem and run the loop?

The loop is already running. You don't need to (and can't) run it again.

```
result = await loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*soups_coro))
```

You're awaiting the wrong thing. `loop.run_until_complete` doesn't return something you can await (a `Future`); it returns the result of whatever you're running until completion.

The reason nothing appears to happen when you call `f` directly is that `f` is an asyncio-style coroutine. As such it returns a future that must be scheduled with the event loop. It doesn't execute until a running event loop tells it to. `loop.run_until_complete` takes care of all of that for you.

To wrap up your question, you want to await `asyncio.gather`.

```
async def f(category, total): 
    urls = [urls_template[category].format(t) for t in t_list]
    soups_coro = map(parseURL_async, urls)

    result = await asyncio.gather(*soups_coro)
```

And you probably also want to include `return result` at the end of `f`, too.

Answer (score 2):

Convert `main()` into async function and execute it by `loop.run_until_complete()`.

When the code has the only one `run_until_complete()` -- everything becomes much easier. In Python 3.7 you will be able to write just `asyncio.run(main())`