# How to start a job and return value before job has completed?

Tags: python, concurrency

I want the following:

```
def start_job_and_return_string():
    start_job() #takes a while  
    return "job started"
```

by calling `start_job_and_return_string` I want to instantly get a string back. Later on the job will dump its results into the filesystem.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234827/wait-for-async-function-to-complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option is to use a thread:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

def start_job():
    sleep(1)
    print("all done!")

def start_job_and_return_string():
    Thread(target=start_job).start()
    return "job started"

print(start_job_and_return_string())
```

prints:

```
job started
all done!
```